# discord.js add 3 roles with 1 command

Tags: discord, discord.js, addition, roles, member

I want add roles to a user when a admin typed activate (user) the bot give the user 3 roles and here is my code

```
  if (message.content === 'activate') {

  const guild = message.guild;

  const role = message.guild.roles.cache.get('842121303616126977');

  const member =   message.mentions.members.first

  member.roles.add(role);
          
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

[`GuildMemberRoleManager.add`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=add) accepts an array of [`RoleResolvable`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/RoleResolvable), which can either be an instance of [`Role`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role) or a [`Snowflake`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/Snowflake).

---

```js
if (message.content === "activate") {
    const member = message.mentions.members.first(); // Note that first is a method, not a property.
    if (!member) return message.channel.send("Member not found.");

    member.roles.add(["RoleID1", "RoleID2", "RoleID3"]);
}
```

Comment: it wont add role to the user i mention

Comment: `client.on('message', message => {

if (message.content === "activate") {
    const member = message.mentions.members.first(); // Note that first is a method, not a property.
if (!member) return message.channel.send("Member not found.");

    member.roles.add(["842121300532920362", "842121301777973298", "842121302708977694"]);

  }

  });`

Comment: @ArabSword Make sure your bot has the `Manage Roles` permission and the IDs you provided are valid. Are you getting any error(s) in the console?

Comment: it has and no errors and not adding roles

Comment: Is your bot's role higher than the ones you're trying to add?

Answer (score 0):

this worked

```
this code worked for me finally `client.on('message', message => {
    
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    console.log(args);

    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();


    if (command == 'activate') {
    const member = message.mentions.members.first(); // Note that first is a method, not a property.


if (!member) return message.channel.send("member not found");

const drole = message.guild.roles.cache.get('842121300532920362');

const prole = message.guild.roles.cache.get('842121301777973298');

const lrole = message.guild.roles.cache.get('842121302708977694');

const frole = message.guild.roles.cache.get('842121305854836826');

member.roles.add(drole);
member.roles.add(lrole);
member.roles.add(prole);
member.roles.remove(frole);
message.channel.send('activated'  + ' <' + '@' + member + '>');
  }


  });`
```